Why do I get "The account does not have permission to access this resource" error when logging in to Bitbucket Cloud from XCode?
When I tried to sign in to my Bitbucket account from XCode, I got an error saying "Your account does not have permission to access this resource".
I used the same app password that I've been using with SourceTree without any problems. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

You have this tagged as "SSH". Are you using SSH?

I was thinking that the reason would be related to not using ssh for logging in. That's why I tagged SSH.

I have had the same issue in XCode. My solution, which isn't the best but as long as you don't share this password with ANYONE you should be OK. I set all the parameters to admin/read/write. A.K.A all of them were ticked. Do that, put the password in, and it works.

COMMENT: I think that the issue with this is that one of the things hasn't been set correctly, but I couldn't tell you which one. You can either take my response and do all of them, or do the grueling task of trial and error to find the specific ones for the task at hand. Hope you find what you are looking for!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yes, that solved my problem. I created another app password with admin privileges and it worked just fine. Thank you for your help!

This is how I fixed it:

Go to App Store Connect, select your profile name at the upper right corner and go to Edit Profile.
Go to Xcode Cloud tab > Integrations
Remove the Bitbucket account without permissions and login with the correct one.
Try the Xcode Cloud setup again

Hope it works for you!
